# Is there any way to use Compass with PHPSass compiler?

Tags: php, sass, compass-sass

Our stylesheets are build in SCSS with Compass mixins. For development we used CodeKit as it's great tool and I really love it. But now we need to implement tools for auto compilation on server side. We used PHPSass ([phpsass.com](http://phpsass.com)) as it supports pure SASS very well. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to attach Compass into it. It does not have build in support yet and Compass is available only as gem package - no way to just download it and put its mixins into project folder. Do someone have any experience with such problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using Sass/Compass via command line?  It has automated compiling via watch or you could run it as a cron.  You could even invoke it via `exec()` if you really had to get PHP involved.

Comment: client wants to have ability to dynamicaly change template (like redefining colors etc) from CMS so I really need to compile templates server side. `exec()` is not a solution - it would work only on custom dedicated servers and we want to create easy and reusable code. That's why PHPSass seems to be excelent.

Comment: If all you need is the mixins, you can grab them here:  https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets.  However, you won't have any of the valuable helper functions like the sprite generator because those are all written in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the mixins from https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets (i think i actually downloaded the compass from some windows/ruby thing)  Caution, not all of compass will work with phpsass.  im currently using a very small subset, i think the border-radius and box model. there seems to be an issue with some sass functions not ported to php.

```
$loadpath = array(pathtosassfiles, pathtocompass);
    $defaultOptions = array(
    'load_paths'     =>   $loadpath  ,
    'cache'          => false,
    'syntax'         => 'scss',
    'extensions'     =>  array('compass'=>array())
    );
$debugoptions = array(
    'line_numbers'   => false,
     'debug_info'    => true,
    'style'          => 'nested', //'compressed' 'compact' 'expanded' 'nested'
    );
$minoptions = array(
    'line_numbers'   => false,
    'debug_info'     => false,
    'style'          => 'compressed', //'compressed' 'compact' 'expanded' 'nested'
    );
//then when you instantiate:
$sass = new SassParser(array_merge($defaultOptions, $minoptions));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just so everyone knows, as of February 11th 2013, phpSASS supports extensions. A post from the developers twitter, "We now have support for extensions, which means Compass. Big thanks to Juan Manuel Vergés Solanas and tsi for the contributions!" http://www.phpsass.com/ https://twitter.com/PHPSass